# Laurent series for a Jacobi Theta function?

Tags: complex-analysis, theta-functions

I would like to know the behaviour of $\vartheta_4$ listed [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) about $q=1$. The Jacobi theta function is undefined at $q=1$. Is it possible to calculate a Laurent series? If so, how would you go about finding this? Do you know of any other ways I can get a simple expression which closely approximates the value of $\vartheta_4$ for $q$ close 1?

Comment: No Laurent series as it isn't meromorphic at $q=1$, the unit circle is a natural boundary. The asymptotic/approximation is known from the $\tau \mapsto -1/\tau$ symmetry